# XQuery: find max value and return relevant information

Tags: max, xquery

I have a XML file containing elements with the following structure:

```
<listing>
    <auction_info>
        <num_bids>29</num_bids>
    </auction_info>
    <item_info>
        <result>item A</result>
    </item_info>
</listing>
<listing>
    <auction_info>
        <num_bids>12</num_bids>
    </auction_info>
    <item_info>
        <result>item B</result>
    </item_info>
</listing>
```

I need a query to calculate the max of num_bids and return the result.In my example,the num_bids 29 is the max number,so need return item A.But in my code below,it returned all results.

```
let $x := //listing
let $max := max($x/auction_info/num_bids)
return $x[//num_bids = $max]/item_info/result
```

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What your expression asks for is "*give me all $x where there is a num_bids, **anywhere** in the document, which is equal to $max.*"  Which is different than "*give me all $x for which **its own** num_bids is equal to $max.*"  The following should do (not tested):

```
let $in  := //listing
let $max := max($in/auction_info/num_bids)
return
   $in[auction_info/num_bids eq $max]/item_info/result
```

If you really want to use the descendant axis, you can change `$x[//xxx]` to `$x[.//xxx]` (see the extra dot?)  The first one says "*for each $x, any xxx descendant from its root*," the second says "*for each $x, any xxx descendant from itself*."  But from your example input, the query above is most likely what you want.