# XML XQuery filter clause

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

Considering the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<publication>
    <scientificPublication>
        <id>2347823476</id>
        <book>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>1</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>0</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>2</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>1</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>1</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
            <chapter>
                <Title>ChapterTitle</Title>
                <sequenceNumber>2</sequenceNumber>
                <correctionNumber>0</correctionNumber>
            </chapter>
        </book>
    </scientificPublication>
</publication>
```

What I need is to retrieve all the chapters with the same `sequenceNumber`, where `correctionNumber` is less than the max of `correctionNumber`.

So in the case of the example it would be the chapters with (`sequenceNumber`,`correctionNumber`): `[(0,0),(0,1),(1,0)]`

My idea was to create a function to return the MAX, considering [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30206069/xquery-find-max-value-and-return-relevant-information) post, and use this as a base to create a clause to get all the chapters with `correctionNumber` less than the MAX. But I'm not sure how would I be able to iterate over the chapters, getting all the `sequenceNumber`, to create this clause.

It would be something like:

```
//chapter[(./*[((sequenceNumber='X')and(correctionNumber<'MAX'))or((sequenceNumber='Y')and(correctionNumber<'MAX'))or...])]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your XML is sorted as your input example, you could try the following XPath 1.0 expression :

```
//sequenceNumber[.=preceding::sequenceNumber or .=following::sequenceNumber][following-sibling::correctionNumber[.<following::correctionNumber[1]]]/parent::chapter
```

We first select the duplicated `sequenceNumber`. Each one fulfill the following-condition : their `correctionNumber` sibling is inferior to the next and first following `correctionNumber`. We finally get the `parent` element of these `sequenceNumber` elements.

Output : 3 chapters (`0,0`;`0,1`;`1,0`)

Answer (score 0):

As a one-line XPath expression:

```
//chapter[sequenceNumber lt max(//sequenceNumber) and correctionNumber lt max(//correctionNumber)]
```

However, depending upon the processor you are using and the size of your documents, you may find that it does not perform as well as if you were to let variables with those max values and use the variables within the predicate filters:

```
let $max-sequence := max(//sequenceNumber)
let $max-correction := max(//correctionNumber)
return
  //chapter[sequenceNumber lt $max-sequence and correctionNumber lt $max-correction]
```